# The characters Rigidbody, falls straight down when movement input is 0 and in the air. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a 3 fps game and I have an issue with the player's movement. when the player is jumping while moving and the movement input is 0 right after the jump, then the player stops in the air and moves upward slightly and then falls straight down(as if hitting an invisible wall). The player only has a Rigidbody and a looking script.

Move input is 0 half way through the jump
[image: Move input is 0 half way through the jump]

Move input is more than 0 through the jump
[image: Move input is more than 0 through the jump]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Movement
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float speedometer;
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 40f)] float GroundSpeed = 10;
    [SerializeField, Range(0f, 20f)] float AirSpeed = 5;

    float maxSpeed ;

    public Vector3 velocity, desiredVelocity, velocityChange;
   
    public float rayHitdistance = 2;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    //Jump
    [Header("Jump")]
    [SerializeField, Range(0f, 20f)] float jumpHight = 5;

    // Inputs
    float inputX, inputZ;
    bool inputJump;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        maxSpeed = GroundSpeed;
    }

    void Inputs()
    {
        inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        inputZ = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        inputJump |= Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Inputs();

        speedometer = rb.velocity.magnitude;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveVelocity();

        if (inputJump && OnGround())
        {
            Jump();
            inputJump = false;
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        float jumpForce = Mathf.Sqrt(-2f * Physics.gravity.y * jumpHight);
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    void MoveVelocity()
    {
        float speed = OnGround() ? GroundSpeed : AirSpeed;

        desiredVelocity = new Vector3(inputX, 0f, inputZ).normalized * speed;
        desiredVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(desiredVelocity);

        velocity =  rb.velocity;
        velocityChange = (desiredVelocity - velocity);
        velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -speed, speed);
        velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -speed, speed);
        velocityChange.y = 0;
       
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocityChange, maxSpeed), ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    }

    bool OnGround()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, rayHitdistance, whatIsGround) ||
                    Physics.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0), Vector3.down, rayHitdistance, whatIsGround) ||
                    Physics.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, 0), Vector3.down, rayHitdistance, whatIsGround) ||
                    Physics.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f), Vector3.down, rayHitdistance, whatIsGround) ||
                    Physics.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0, -0.5f), Vector3.down, rayHitdistance, whatIsGround))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {           
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue most probably lies in `MoveVelocity`.

If you have no input then `desiredVelocity` is a **zero vector**. Any further transformation of this (`normalize` and `InverseTransformPoint`) will also return a zero vector.

And therefore

```
velocityChange = (desiredVelocity - velocity);
```

results in `-velocity` so exactly inverting the current velocity.

You then set the `y` component to `0` and clamp on `x` and `z` but sooner or later basically you completely erase any velocity on `x` and `z`.

Therefore the object only continues moving according to the physics on the `y` axis.

---

I think you could simply check if there even is any input and only apply the change in that case:

```
void MoveVelocity()
{
    // If there is no input there is nothing to do
    if(Mathf.Approximately(inputX, 0) && Mathf.Approximately(inputZ, 0)) return;

    var speed = OnGround() ? GroundSpeed : AirSpeed;

    desiredVelocity = new Vector3(inputX, 0f, inputZ).normalized * speed;
    desiredVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(desiredVelocity);

    velocity = rb.velocity;
    velocityChange = (desiredVelocity - velocity);
    velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -speed, speed);
    velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -speed, speed);
    velocityChange.y = 0;
   
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocityChange, maxSpeed), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Comment: Thanx, this fixed the jumping problem, but now when the player isn't pressing any keys the RB slides, until stopping gradually. I added a physics material to add more friction, but that also reduces the movement speed, so that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell cause we don't know what your speed variable is and what your maxspeed variable is, but most likely when your inputX is 0, desired velocity is just very quick going to 0. The upward movement seems normal and both images match in that regard. To fix this, I recommend increasing and reducing the x velocity gradually instead of instantly. I like to have ground acceleration, air acceleration, max ground speed, max air speed, air drag, and ground drag. That way you have full control of the feel of movement.

It'd be something like:

```
// Bases speed adjustments on whether you're on ground or in air
bool onGround = OnGround();
float speed = onGround ? GroundSpeed : AirSpeed;
float accel = onGround ? GroundAccel : AirAccel;
float drag = onGround ? GroundDrag : AirDrag;

// This part uses drag if you're stopping or accel if you're moving
bool vel = inputX != 0 ? accel : drag;

// Gets the speed you want to moving
var inputVector = new Vector3(inputX, 0f, inputZ).normalized * speed;
desiredVelocity.z = inputVector.z;

// Gradually changes horizontal speed
desiredVelocity.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(desiredVelocity.x, inputVector.x, vel * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```